# How to store a stack in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I've been trying to store a stack in SharedPreferences as a set through the `putStringSet` API in `SharedPreferences`.

In the write method, I do this:
`putStringSet(KEY, new LinkedHashSet(stack));`

When I read, I do this:
`getStringSet(KEY, null)` into a `Set`.

I reverse the elements in the set by converting to a list using `Collections.reverse(list)`, and all the elements to the stack.

Things are great when I write into `SharedPreferences`, but the order of elements is completely messed up when I read.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type are the elements in the stack?

Comment: I have only strings on the stack

Comment: when you read why don't you put them in a LinkedHashSet  instead of Set , doing this you can keep the inserted order.

Comment: @Lazai: Because `SharedPreferences` will not return a `LinkedHashSet`. `SharedPreferences` considers a string set to be unordered.

Comment: Other than using another storage option (see Code-Apprentice's answer), the standard solution for putting random stuff into `SharedPreferences` is to convert that stuff into JSON, storing the JSON as a simple string.

Comment: yes, but I'm trying to avoid having to use gson serialization/de-serialization on the UI thread/background thread. That would be last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your stack elements to a comma separated String and then use putString to save it.

For example, if your stack contains the following:

```
| "4" |
| "3" |
| "2" |
| "1" |
| "0" |
-------
```

You should convert it to the String "0,1,2,3,4" and save it to `SharedPreferences`.

To rebuild your stack, get the String from the `SharedPreferences`, split it by the comma separator and push it in order to the stack.

Comment: Yes, i was just going to post this as an answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` is probably not the best solution. You would be better served by using a flat file or a database. With that said, you could accomplish this by storing the values individually and programmatically generate a key for each element.